# C# .NET MVC List inside array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, list

I have the following snippet of code. This is for an assignment and I'm not understanding what it is that is happening here. I'm supposed to create a styled list using the following:

```
{
  "students": [{
    "Name" : "Robert Mcguffin",
    "Registered" : "2014-07-20 05:34:16",
    "Student No:" : 1
} , {
    "Name" : "Agathe Dubois",
    "Registered" : "2014-05-30 09:46:26",
    "Student No:" : 2
} , {
    "Name" : "Steven Corral",
    "Registered" : "2015-02-11 09:58:16",
    "Student No:" : 3
}]}
```

I'm not sure what's going on here but I'm assuming it's a list inside an array. I'm not even sure that's possible. How would I declare this in MVC? If it's not a list inside an array then what is going on here?

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not list inside an array, it called JSON string.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really going to help me finish this assignment.

Comment: It an object (with a property students) which is an array/collection containing 3 objects with properties Name, Registered and Student No

Comment: Its an array of objects in json. What is it that you want to do with it? In mvc you can return this from an action method. Create a 'list<student>() lst' and the return json(new { students = lst } );

Comment: If you did became an answer of your question and understood what you wanted to know, then please don't change/extend your question in order to ask a totally different one. In such case you should create a new question. Otherwise this will be a never ending story. Have a look at the SO [help section about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for more information.

Comment: Thank you pasty I will ask a different question. I did not know that I couldn't change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is a JSON string with a List of Student Objects. Those Student objects have the properties Name, Registered and StudentNo.

Use this, so you can start making some parallelism between a JSON string and C# classes. Change the string and play a bit with it :)

http://json2csharp.com/